# Streamlit plot 2 graphs

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, streamlit

I'm new in Python and Streamlit, I have issues to plot two graphs on Streamlit.

On jupyter notebook it's working very well with this code:

```py
train_size = X_train.shape[0]
f,axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(20,10))

axs[0].plot(df['date'][:train_size], df['close'][:train_size], color='black')
axs[0].plot(df['date'][train_size:], linear_regression_validation_predict, color='red')
axs[0].plot(df['date'][train_size:], df['close'][train_size:], color='green')
axs[1].plot(df['date'][train_size:], linear_regression_validation_predict, color='red')
axs[1].plot(df['date'][train_size:], df['close'][train_size:], color='green')
```

but on streamlit when I try this code:

```py
train_size = X_train.shape[0]
f,axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(20,10))

axs[0].plot(df['date'][:train_size], df['close'][:train_size], color='black')
axs[0].plot(df['date'][train_size:], linear_regression_validation_predict, color='red')
axs[0].plot(df['date'][train_size:], df['close'][train_size:], color='green')
axs[1].plot(df['date'][train_size:], linear_regression_validation_predict, color='red')
axs[1].plot(df['date'][train_size:], df['close'][train_size:], color='green')

st.pyplot(fig=f)
```

I have only the first graph displayed.

I'm looking forward for your feedback.

Comment: Hi! I could not reproduce. It gives me 2 subplots as expected on Streamlit. Have you tried with simpler lists, like `axs[0].plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 25, 43, 12], color='black')` or `axs[0].plot([5, 6], [18, 45], color='red')`?